# Separate email address by its domain name

Tags: c#, vb.net, excel

I have an xls file that contains over 20000 email addresses. I want to separate the email address programmatically by its domain name, such as Gmail, Yahoo, etc., into separate files.

How can I do that in VB.NET or C#?

Comment: Tell us what you have done so far, and where you get stuck. we don't know if you need help in opening XLS or validating email address...or something else, so we can't give an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft office has a library available for C# (and I assume VB.NET as well) called `OpenXML`. It allows for the creation and reading of the various types of files supported by the Office suite (Word-doc/docx, Excel-xls/xlsx etc).

There is a fantastic library that wraps `OpenXML` called [ClosedXML](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/). Its a super easy to use library and is well documented in the link.

Once you read in the file, I would incorporate code like this .NET fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/jkKngk

Answer (score 0):

```
MailAddress address = new MailAddress("xyz@yahoo.com");
string host = address.Host; // host contains yahoo.com
```